# How to filter web part content based on current wiki page taxonomy/category/keywords?

Tags: web-part, filter, wiki

I have a series of simple wiki pages inside a Wiki Library (SharePoint 2010);
As a test on a page, I have added a web part showing all wiki pages (w/ custom view), but I'd like to extend this web part to only show pages that are of the same category (or other column/key). Kind of an semi-automatic "Related pages" where I only have to make sure all my pages are correctly categorized.

Is that possible ?

I see a lot of web parts, but can't find what to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you want to limit your search results to wiki pages only containing a specific enterprise keyword? If so, that is quite easy - just add a query rule:

[image: filter results by enterprise tags]

Comment: No, I want automatic search results to appear when viewing a page.

Comment: The query result thing you show is not possible for me. I'm only managing a subsite, or teamsite I think